# Visual C++ not know function return value which is a user defined class

Tags: class, visual-c++

I have,

time.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H
class time
{
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
public:
    enum pmORam {am,pm};
    time(void);
    time(int,int,int);
    void printtime(void);
    time subtime(time &);
    const time &operator=(const time &);
    void setTime(int,int,int);
    ~time(void);
};
#endif
```

time.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"



using namespace std;


time::time(void)
{
    hour=0;
    minute=0;
    second=0;
}
time::time(int hr,int min,int sec)
{
    setTime(hr,min,sec);
}

void time::printtime(void)
{
    enum pmORam p;

    if(hour<=12 && hour>=0)
        cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<hour<<":"<<setw(2)<<minute<<":"<<setw(2)<<second<<p.am<<endl;
    else 
        if(hour>12 && hour<=23)
        {
            hour=hour%12;
            cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<hour<<":"<<setw(2)<<minute<<":"<<setw(2)<<second<<p.pm<<endl;
        }
}
const time &time::operator=(const time &t)
{
    hour=t.hour;
    minute=t.minute;
    second=t.second;
    return *this;
}
time time::subtime(time &m)
{
    if(hour>m.hour)
    {
        if(m.second>second)
        {
            minute=minute-1;
            second=(second+60)-m.second;
        }
        second=second-m.second;
        if(m.minute>minute)
        {
            hour=hour-1;
            minute=(minute+60)-m.minute;
        }
        minute=minute-m.minute;
        hour=hour-m.hour;
    }
    if(second>m.second)
    {
        m. minute=m.minute-1;
        m.second=(m.second+60)-second;
    }
    m.second=m.second-second;
    if(minute>m.minute)
    {
        m.hour=m.hour-1;
        m.minute=(m.minute+60)-minute;
    }
    m.hour=hour-m.hour;
    return *this;
}
void time::setTime(int hr,int min,int sec)
{
    hour=(hr>=0 && hr<=23)? hr: 0;
    minute=(min>=0 && min<60)? min:0;
    second=(sec>=0 && sec<60)? sec:0;
}
time::~time(void)
{
}
```

But in time.cpp i get to this Errors:

```
 IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "time time::subtime(time &)"
 IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "const time &time::operator=(const time &)"
'time::time(const time &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'time *const ' to 'const time &' 
'int time::subtime(time &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'time time::subtime(time &)'
'int &time::operator =(const time &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'const time &time::operator =(const time &)'
function "time" is not a type name
```

What is Problem?

**Edit: New code to fix naming conflict**

time.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"



using namespace std;


timea::timea(void)
{
    hour=0;
    minute=0;
    second=0;
}
timea::timea(int hr,int min,int sec)
{
    setTime(hr,min,sec);
}

void timea::printtime(void)
{
    enum timea::pmORam p;

    if(hour<=12 && hour>=0)
        cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<hour<<":"<<setw(2)<<minute<<":"<<setw(2)<<second<<p.am<<endl;
    else 
        if(hour>12 && hour<=23)
        {
            hour=hour%12;
            cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<hour<<":"<<setw(2)<<minute<<":"<<setw(2)<<second<<p.pm<<endl;
        }
}
const timea &timea::operator=(const timea &t)
{
    hour=t.hour;
    minute=t.minute;
    second=t.second;
    return *this;
}
timea timea::subtime(timea &m)
{
    if(hour>m.hour)
    {
        if(m.second>second)
        {
            minute=minute-1;
            second=(second+60)-m.second;
        }
        second=second-m.second;
        if(m.minute>minute)
        {
            hour=hour-1;
            minute=(minute+60)-m.minute;
        }
        minute=minute-m.minute;
        hour=hour-m.hour;
    }
    if(second>m.second)
    {
        m. minute=m.minute-1;
        m.second=(m.second+60)-second;
    }
    m.second=m.second-second;
    if(minute>m.minute)
    {
        m.hour=m.hour-1;
        m.minute=(m.minute+60)-minute;
    }
    m.hour=hour-m.hour;
    return *this;
}
void timea::setTime(int hr,int min,int sec)
{
    hour=(hr>=0 && hr<=23)? hr: 0;
    minute=(min>=0 && min<60)? min:0;
    second=(sec>=0 && sec<60)? sec:0;
}
timea::~timea(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Anything above the line `#include "stdafx.h"` usually gets ignored due to precompiled header processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a header file in the Standard library named `time.h`.  It's likely that either

- You're including the system header file when you wanted your own, or
- System header files are pulling in yours when they wanted the standard one

or both.  Find a different name for your header.

In addition, the identifier `time` in the global namespace is used by a function in the Standard library (hence the error `function "time" is not a type name`).  So put yours inside a namespace or change the class name.

Specifically, your errors are caused by ignoring this rule, found in 17.6.4.3.3:

> Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with extern "C" linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace.
>
> Each function signature from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"` linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

Comment: previous errors solved,now enum pmORam p; in time.cpp get to this error when i use p:
"expression must have class type", what is problem?

Comment: @user197508: Did you fix the problems with name conflicts?  I can't see the new version of your code.  You can add it to the question, mark it as "edit: new code to fix naming conflict" and leave the old code in there as well.

Comment: Now "enum pmORam p;" in "time.cpp" get to this error when i use "p": "expression must have class type", what is problem?

Comment: `p.am` is meaningless. As far as I can tell, you want `"am"` there (a two-character string literal). Similarly, replace `p.pm` with `"pm"`